# How can I keep space, tab, CR and LF?

Tags: jquery, html

The string `s` includes space, tab, CR and LF. `alert()` can render format correctly,
but `$("#mydiv").text(s)`lost CR and LF, I hope `$("#mydiv").text(s)` can render format correctly, how can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#Button1").bind("click", function () {
                alert(s);
                $("#mydiv").text(s);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" /></p>
    <div id="mydiv">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It may make more sense to use the [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/button) element instead of `<input>`.

Answer (score 4):

You can give the `#mydiv` a bit of CSS style for this:

```
#mydiv { white-space: pre; }
```

The problem is, that the jQuery `.text()` method just sets the HTML text, and HTML elements join all consecutive white space characters to a single space and also strip the first and last, if they're block elements (with `<pre>` the notable exception). This CSS declaration tells the div to act like a `<pre>` in this situation.

Comment: Perhaps "all consecutive whitespace is treated as a single space" is better than "don't respect white space".

Answer (score -1):

Try to use .html(s) instead of .text(s)